# Python loop through tuple list adding a value from pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tuples

I am trying to loop through a list of tuples adding a value to the end of each one that corresponds to a value in a column in a pandas data frame.

```
df1 = [(1,2),(4,5),(8,9)]

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha': [2, 4, 8],
                    'Beta': ["a","b","c"]})

df3 = []

for i in df1:
    print(i)

for i,j in df2["Beta"], df1:
    j = j + (i,)
    df3.append(j)

print(df3)
```

I would expect print(df3) to display the following:

```
[(1, 2, 'a'), (4, 5, 'b'), (8, 9, 'c')]
```

However, I get an error stating too many values to unpack.

Comment: Don't forget you can upvote answers too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip`, list comprehension solution:

```
df3 = [j + (i,) for i,j in zip(df2["Beta"], df1)]
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
for i,j in zip(df2["Beta"], df1):
    j = j + (i,)
    df3.append(j)
```

---

```
print(df3)
[(1, 2, 'a'), (4, 5, 'b'), (8, 9, 'c')]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using a list comprehension would be:

```
[(*i, j) for i, j in zip(df1,  df2.Beta)]
# [(1, 2, 'a'), (4, 5, 'b'), (8, 9, 'c')]
```

---

Or you could also `map` with `operator.add`:

```
from operator import add
list(map(add, df1, df2.Beta.map(tuple)))
# [(1, 2, 'a'), (4, 5, 'b'), (8, 9, 'c')]
```

Or working from pandas:

```
(pd.Series(df1) + df2.Beta.map(tuple)).values.tolist()
# [(1, 2, 'a'), (4, 5, 'b'), (8, 9, 'c')]
```